Browser Crashes with WordPress Plugin SimpleTOC After Update to 6.6.x in reusable block
I am the creator of the SimpleTOC plugin for WordPress (SimpleTOC Plugin). After updating to WordPress 6.6.x (including 6.6.1), my plugin causes the browser to crash and freeze whenever the block is used in any configuration as a reusable block. This happens even in Chrome, making it impossible to debug.
Here is a snippet of the relevant code that seems to cause the issue:
return (
    <div { ...blockProps }>
        { controls }
        { controlssidebar }
        { /* Conditional rendering based on autoupdate attribute */ }
        { autoupdateOption &&
        autoupdate &&
        ( returnisSaving || returnisSavingNonPostEntityChanges ) ? (
            <Spinner />
        ) : (
            <ServerSideRender
                block="simpletoc/toc"
                attributes={ attributes }
            />
        ) }
    </div>
);

Full Code:
The complete code is available on GitHub: SimpleTOC Plugin - edit.js
I've tried removing the conditional rendering logic with returnisSaving and similar attributes, but the issue persists. Many users have reported this problem, and I am unsure how to fix it. Given that the problem started with the release of WordPress 6.6.x, I believe it requires changes on my end.
Steps Taken:

Reviewed all functions within the plugin.
Removed conditional rendering related to returnisSaving and other attributes.
Investigated WordPress 6.6.x changes, specifically regarding Synced Patterns and the Block API.
Updated all dependencies.

Additional Context:

The plugin worked perfectly before the update to WordPress 6.6.x.
The crash happens when using Synced Patterns (formerly Reusable Blocks).

Request:
Any suggestions on what might be causing this issue or how to debug it effectively would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

i can't reproduce the problem and it's working without crash in my dry environment setup. maybe other plugins have conflict with it?

I have many users complaining and it is way to replicate:

use the latest WP version 6.6.1
Install SimpleTOC
Put a SimpleTOC block into the Gutenberg editor.
Create a reusable block from this SimpleTOC block.
Crash

You can use tastewp to test this quickly
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-crashes-in-word-press-6-6-1-backend/ More users complaining and I could easily reproduce it

i use testwp and make some test but still can't reproduce the crash problem. maybe i am doing it wrong? use admin as username and password: https://composeactivity.s2-tastewp.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=7&action=edit

Steps to reproduce:
Create a new tastewp instance and log in on a Chrome browser
Install SimpelTOC, activate it and deactivate all other plugins
Edit Sample Page and add a SimpleTOC
Activate the “Hide SimpleTOC” option and switch to “Hide in accordion menu. Adds minimal JS and CSS.”
Click Create Pattern in the block toolbar menu
At this point, the browser (latest Chrome) will freeze.
